# Want to start a slide show by opening image files by subprocess.Popen() of python on windows 10 PC

Tags: python, windows

I want to start a slide show by opening a image file by `subprocess.Popen()` of python on windows 10 PC, and change images by `pyautogui.press('right')`. More than one image files are in the folder "test", and the code is as follows:

```py
import subprocess
from time import sleep
import pyautogui

image = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')  + r'\test\test1.jpg'
subprocess.Popen(['start',image],shell=True)

sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('F11') #full screen
sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('right')
```

The image was successfully opened by Windows Photo, but the image didn't change at all.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is not a Python issue.
Issuing the command "start **image**" in cmd only opens that photo and not the full "album" of the current directory. Try searching on Windows forums maybe?